# Detecting malaria using tensor flow error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I was trying a code to detect malaria using tensorflow but i faced this problem

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (22046, 1, 2) for Tensor 'Placeholder_5:0', which has shape '(?, 2)'
```

And this is the code

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x , y , test_size = 0.2 , random_state = 42)
x_train = x_train.reshape(22046 , 125 * 125) / 255                       
x_test  = x_test.reshape(5512 , 125 * 125) / 255
with tf.Session() as sess:
    y_train = sess.run(tf.one_hot(y_train , 2))                    
    y_test  = sess.run(tf.one_hot(y_test, 2 )) 
learning_rate = 0.01
epochs        = 10
batch_size    = 100   
batches       = int(x_train.shape[0] / batch_size)  
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , [None , 15625])                     
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , [None , 2])                  
W = tf.Variable(.1 * np.random.randn(15625, 2).astype(np.float32))   
B = tf.Variable(.1 * np.random.randn(2).astype(np.float32))   
pred      = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(X , W) , B)) 
cost      = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = pred, labels = Y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

with tf.Session() as sesh:
    sesh.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for i in range(batches):
            offset = i * epoch
            x = x_train[offset : offset + batch_size]
            y = y_train[offset : offset + batch_size]
            sesh.run(optimizer , feed_dict = {X : x_train , Y : y_train})
            c = sesh.run(cost  , feed_dict = {X : x_train , Y : y_train})
        print(f'epoch:{epoch : 2d} cost={c : .4f}')
        correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
        acc = accuracy.eval({X: x_test, Y: y_test})
        print(f'Accuracy: {acc * 100:.2f}%')


        fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 10, figsize=(8, 4))
        for img, ax in zip(x_test[:10], axes):
            guess = np.argmax(sesh.run(pred, feed_dict={X: [img]}))
            ax.set_title(guess)
            ax.imshow(img.reshape((125, 125)))
            ax.axis('off')
```

i tried desperately to run the code by changing the placeholder from

`Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , [None , 2])`

To

`Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32 , [None , 1 , 2])`

But it gets my another error of the same type.

I tried this by accident and it worked just fine "But the accuracy was very low 49%" but i still need more information or another solution if there is more accurate or proper one.

`y_train = np.reshape(y_train , (22046 , 2))`

And can anyone recommend my a good website,course or any place where i can learn Tensorflow in a proper way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your code as text; see why [an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) (and same with the [error messages](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/))

Comment: Sorry for this,it's my first post i'm new here